# Preference Activity

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferenceactivity, preferencefragment

I am creating a settings activity for my android application, one of the options it to allow password or not, I do not just want that option to be checked anyhow so I want it to ask for a password before changing the preference. I want a Dialog fragment to pop up and ask for the password before the preference changes, after changing, the **onPreferenceChange** method should be called and if the password is correct the preference can change by returning **true**;

The issue is that my settings fragment cannot recognize **getFragmentManager()**  and even if I do **getActivity.getFragmentManager** it gives an error that the ***preferencefragment cannot be cast to the dialog***. The dialog works for normal activities in the project but not the preference fragment.

This is the dialogfragment showing where the activity is to be casted

```
public class password_dialog extends DialogFragment {
public interface PasswordDialogListener {
    void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog, String password);

    void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog);
}

PasswordDialogListener mListener;


@Override
public void onAttach(Context activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    // Verify that the host activity implements the callback interface
    try {
        // Instantiate the PasswordDialogListener so we can send events to the host
        mListener = (PasswordDialogListener) activity;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e("dialog",e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

.
.
.

This is the main code of the preference fragment the class extends extends **PreferenceFragmentCompat** and **implements Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener, password_dialog.PasswordDialogListener**

```
 @Override
public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    Preference preference = findPreference(getString(R.string.printSetting));

    /*****Realm*****/
    Realm.init(getActivity());
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

    preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
    DialogFragment PasswordDialogFragment = new password_dialog();
    PasswordDialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "Password");

    if (passwordIsCorrect) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

And because of that it gives a null pointer exception because **mListener** is not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

> Since you are only facing the error to `getFragmentManager()`.
>
> try to change your code from `getFragmentManager()` to
>   `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead.

hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing support and not support classes. When you're importing a class `IDE` suggest you to import one of two classes with the same name:

[image]

As you already use `PreferenceFragmentCompat`(which is class from support library) you should use support fragment related classes:

```
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.preference.Preference;
import android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;

public class PreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat implements Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener {

    @Override public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object o) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        DialogFragment PasswordDialogFragment = get();
        PasswordDialogFragment.show(fragmentManager, "Password");
        return true;
    }
}
```